# Git pushing with a different account

Tags: git, github

So I am trying to push to my repo under my account and everytime I try to use the command git push I get the following error:

```
remote: Permission to kpath001/kpath001.github.io.git denied to alphadsi.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/kpath001/kpath001.github.io.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I am trying to figure out how do I delete this "alphadsi" account I have on my mac so I can start using my original kpath001 profile to properly use the git commands without getting access denied error or the 403 error.

I searched multiple stackoverflow questions and nothing seems to relate....will be a big help

**Solution: delete the internet account from Mac OSX keychain**

Comment: Can't you simply grant the other user read/write access so you can use either at any time?

Comment: Could you possibly delete the git on mac and re-install it and set it up with my account again? Will this work or would it still throw me a similar error?

Comment: I don't want to do that because I want the profile to show that I was the user who edited my website rather than someone else

Comment: I wouldn't know about Mac, sorry. I could suggest you install Atlassian SourceTree and tell it that you already have Git installed (as in, don't tell it to install git again). It may tell you about any accounts you may have set up there.

Comment: Please don't edit your post to include a solution, post it as an answer instead and mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete the internet account from Mac OSX keychain

Answer (score 0):

At first, I think you should make sure this is your repo. If you git clone other's repo, you can't push to origin master.

Then I think you can check the git configuration. it may be in `.bash_profile` or somewhere you add. Try to use `git config --global user.name yours` and `git config --global user.email yours` to config your account in your computer again. For me, I add it to my `.bash_profile`.

Comment: I have verfied this as well and yes the git conifg file has the github user as kpath001 but for some reason when i call git push on any repo I created in my kpath001 account it uses this "alphadsi" account for somereason and I was wondering if there is a way to get rid of it entirely

Comment: "alphadsi" is your name ever used ? have you ever config your git info in other place in your compuer(which like .bashrc .bash_profile or any other files)?